# VB.net Function that returns a populated object not working

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to create a function that returns an object of type.  This function below is currently inside my dataclass and can be called from any object that inherits the dataclass.  My problem is when I try and return my object.  It populates just fine while I am inside the function.  When I get back out to the calling object its all empty like it's a new object.

Here's the function....

```
    Public Overloads Function GetClassFromDB(ByVal ID As Integer) As Object
        Try
            Dim BaseObject As New Object
            Dim objDerived As Type = MyBase.GetType()
            Dim TableName As String = String.Empty
            Dim SQL As New LottoPayload.SQLiDataClass
            Dim SQLString As String = String.Empty
            Dim SQLCommand As SQLiteCommand = Nothing
            Dim SQLConnection As SQLiteConnection = Nothing
            Dim SQLiteDRObj As SQLiteDataReader = Nothing
            Dim SQLResultsTable As New DataTable

            'Create an instance of the base object
            BaseObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objDerived)
            'Get the tablename from the object
            TableName = objDerived.GetProperty("TableName").GetValue(BaseObject, Nothing).ToString

            SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE ID = '" & ID.ToString & "' LIMIT 1"
            SQLConnection = SQL.GetSqlConnection()

            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConnection)
            SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString

            SQLiteDRObj = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

            SQLResultsTable.Load(SQLiteDRObj)
            If SQLResultsTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Row As DataRow In SQLResultsTable.Rows

                    For Each Column As DataColumn In Row.Table.Columns

                        Dim ColumnName As String = Column.ColumnName.ToString
                        Console.WriteLine(Row.Item(ColumnName))
                        Dim ColumnValue As Object = Row.Item(ColumnName)
                        Console.WriteLine(Column.DataType.Name & "    ")
                        Select Case Column.DataType.Name
                            Case "Int64"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As Integer
                                Integer.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case "Double"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As Double
                                Double.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case "String"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                ConvertedValue = ColumnValue.ToString
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case Else
                                Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                ConvertedValue = "NotSet"
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                        End Select

                    Next
                Next
            End If

            Return objDerived

            SQLiteDRObj.Close()
            SQLConnection.Close()
            SQLConnection.Dispose()
            'Return False
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

and this is how it would be called.

```
        Dim objResults As New myapp.objResult
        Dim ID As Integer = 3
        objResults.GetClassFromDB(ID)
```

Question #1 - When I return the object from `GetClassFromDB` objResults is empty eventhough it had data up until the `Return objDerived`.  Why is this the case?

Question #2 - Is there a way I can eliminate that `Select Case` area and consolidate the code by using reflection?

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Object Is Filled Here]
[image: Object is Empty Here]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be returning `BaseObject` rather than `objDerived`, given that `objDerived` is actually a `Type` object that represents the type of the object created rather than the object itself?  Maybe it would be clearer if you didn't use appalling names like `objDerived` in the first place.

Comment: I tried to return BaseObject before and I get the same results with an empty object.  In regards to the naming, I just plain don't know any better.  Perhaps you can show how you would name them.  I'm trying to learn and teach myself good practices so I value your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your method returns an object, but you are not assigning it to a variable anywhere.  You need to assign the return value of the method to a variable

```
Dim someVariable As Object = objResults.GetClassFromDB(ID)
```

Also, your method is strange in that it returns an object if the code runs successfully but a boolean if there is an exception, which you silently swallow  (also a bad practice).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Perhaps I've gone down the wrong direction with my function.  I don't want to cast the return value from `GetClassFromDB` to `someVariable`.  What I was trying to do was populate `objResults` with the data returned from `GetClassFromDB`

Comment: In that case, I would think you could just make a Shared method on the objResult class and call it like this:  `Dim newObjResult As objResult = objResult.GetClassFromDB(ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the wrong object. objDerived is a Type, not the object that you are setting. You need to return BaseObject. Also, realize that your code to close and dispose the SqlCommand and Connection won't be hit since it's after the return operator. It's best here to wrap the connection and command in Using clauses which will ensure they will be disposed once they go out of scope. See if the following works:

```
Public Overloads Function GetClassFromDB(ByVal ID As Integer) As Object
        Try
            Dim BaseObject As New Object
            Dim objDerived As Type = MyBase.GetType()
            Dim TableName As String = String.Empty
            Dim SQL As New LottoPayload.SQLiDataClass
            Dim SQLString As String = String.Empty
            Using SQLConnection As SQLiteConnection = Nothing
            Using SQLCommand As SQLiteCommand = Nothing
            Dim SQLiteDRObj As SQLiteDataReader = Nothing
            Dim SQLResultsTable As New DataTable

            'Create an instance of the base object
            BaseObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objDerived)
            'Get the tablename from the object
            TableName = objDerived.GetProperty("TableName").GetValue(BaseObject, Nothing).ToString

            SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE ID = '" & ID.ToString & "' LIMIT 1"
            SQLConnection = SQL.GetSqlConnection()

            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConnection)
            SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString

            SQLiteDRObj = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

            SQLResultsTable.Load(SQLiteDRObj)
            If SQLResultsTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Row As DataRow In SQLResultsTable.Rows

                    For Each Column As DataColumn In Row.Table.Columns

                        Dim ColumnName As String = Column.ColumnName.ToString
                        Console.WriteLine(Row.Item(ColumnName))
                        Dim ColumnValue As Object = Row.Item(ColumnName)
                        Console.WriteLine(Column.DataType.Name & "    ")
                        Select Case Column.DataType.Name
                            Case "Int64"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As Integer
                                Integer.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case "Double"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As Double
                                Double.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case "String"
                                Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                ConvertedValue = ColumnValue.ToString
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                            Case Else
                                Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                ConvertedValue = "NotSet"
                                objDerived.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(BaseObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                        End Select

                    Next
                Next
            End If


            End Using ' Sql Command
            End Using ' Sql Connection
            Return BaseObject

            'Return False
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

End Class

From your second screen shot, you don't appear to be setting anything to the return of the GetClassFromDB(ID) method. It should probably be something like:

```
Dim result = objResults.GetClassFromDB(ID)
' Do something with result
```

Comment: Hi Jim,  Thanks for the response.  Yes I was noticing that those commands were not getting hit.  I didn't quite put 2 and 2 together on why it was happening.  Now I understand.  Thank you for that.  Please also see my response to Chris Dunaway above to answer my original question.  Thanks again.

Comment: See my edit to this post. If you want to populate the given object instance rather than returning a populated instance, you remove BaseObject completely and in your setvalue methods, refer to Me not BaseObject. (Personally, I think the factory method implementation you have is a better design decision than mutating the current object that it sounds like you want to do.)

Comment: Hi Jim.  Thanks once again in taking the time to respond.  Your last comment intrigued me.  You said the way I have the code written now is a better design decision than if I want to change the current object.  Can you explain?  I'm trying to understand the "why".

Comment: I've been thinking about your last comment.  If I keep the function the way it is, then I will have to create two of the same objects. the first object to call the function, and the second object to push the results into.  Also, If I use the "Me" instead of BaseObject I will not get all of the properties since the base object has additional properties not contained in objresult